# How can Obito use his Mangekyo so often?

Tags: naruto

It's been said that excessive use of the Mangekyo Sharingan causes blindness and eye-bleeding, as demonstrated by Itachi. However, Obito used his Mangekyo almost constantly nearly every time he's made an appearance. How come he has shown no signs of pain, blindness or eye-bleeding?

My own theory on this is that the Senju DNA Madara used to rebuild his body has something to do with it, but I have never seen this explicitly stated. If it has, can you tell me where or explain how this works in more detail.

Comment: Kamui doesn't require much chakra. And as you said, senju DNA also might have something to do with his chakra level.

Comment: Senju DNA is, after all, the answer to all the plotholes.

Comment: Related: [How does the Mangekyo Sharingan blind its wielder, and why are some wielders not blinded?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3029/310)

Answer (score 11):

Obito's left Sharingan is in posession of Hatake Kakashi, so let's compare Obito with Kakashi and the other known Uchihas.

**Hatake Kakashi**

To use Mangekyou Sharingan Kakashi needs to accumulate a lot of chakra before he can use Kamui on Deidara's arm. The size of the object determines the amount of chakra he needs as seen in the case where he tried to blow the neck of Juubi with that jutsu (thus, Sahan De Silva's comment is not very correct). Since he is not an Uchiha, he requires a lot more chakra and puts more burden on him than it should be as he himself mentioned. Kakashi also suffered the side effect of overusing the Mangekyou Sharingan which he mentioned during the fight between him and Sasuke.

**Uchiha Itachi**

Itachi was seen bleeding when using his Mangekyou Sharingan, especially when he use Amaterasu. This is due to the strain the jutsu puts on the eye. Itachi also suffers the other side effects of losing eyesight and is in pain when using it, although since he was dying at the time he was fighting Sasuke, it can also be said that the pain is also from him over-exerting himself.

**Uchiha Sasuke**

Sasuke also suffered the same side effect of losing eyesight and bleeding when using Amaterasu, much like Itachi was. Since Sasuke was healthy and not sickly like Itachi, it can be determined that overusing Mangekyou Sharingan puts the user in pain. He later recovered from it by transplanting Itachi's eyes and gained the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan.

**Uchiha Madara**

Uchiha Madara also suffered the same side effect and was thus *forced* to take his brother's eyes. He no longer get the negative side effects after awakening his Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan.

Now, based on this fact, the only difference Obito has compared to the other Mangekyou Sharingan users is that he possessed the Senju DNA. The conclusion is, Obito didn't suffer the negative side effects of the Mangekyou Sharingan due to the Senju DNA he possessed.

Answer (score 0):

i think obito had eternal mangekyou. in his fight against the paper akatsuki lady he uses izanagi to rewrite his own death (same thing madara used). this is confusing because up until this you think obito only has one eye / sharingan since he gave his other to kakashi. izanagi causes one to lose sight in one of their eyes. there is a scene where obito is standing over madara's body and behind him there is a wall of hundreds of sharingan, most likely collected from the slaughter of the uchiha done by obito and itachi. i think obito replaced his eyes with some of these sharingan, which would explain his ability to use izanagi and his ability to constantly use his mangekyou sharingan without any negative side effects

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.

Comment: naruto pedia and the show lol

Comment: Please cite specific chapters/episodes/websites etc. This is for easier verification to those who might come upon your answer. References like 'naruto pedia and the show' is vague and do not help validate your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess obito's power to make such frequent use of his sharingan comes from the fact that he has hashirams cells embedded him so now that he has the physical energy of the senju clan he shouldn't find it difficult to make use of his mangekyou frequently